# Domain registration for using Oauth?

Tags: angularjs, grails, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am planning to use Oauth 2.0 using groovy grails and angular js.

I read all the forums and sites to find only examples of oauth and oauth2.0 implementation, but before I go ahead through the learning curve, I would like to know whethere I need to have my website registered with domain?

Currently I am working on prototype on local host using tomcat and Netbeans IDE. Can I implement oauth with local host running on tomcat?

Comment: Are you talking about using an OAuth provider - like, signin in your application through Google - or become an OAuth provider, that is, 3rd party applications will redirect their user to your platform in order to perform authentication?

Comment: @FlavioFerrara Ferrara "signin in your application through Google" is my requirement

Comment: Then, you absolutely need no domain name for that. In fact, you will be only a *client* of an OAuth provider.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/ for a good starting point.

Comment: @FlavioFerrara Hi Flavio thanks for your answer. I have a question before I start coding oauth. Is it better to authenticate a user using (angular+oauth) or authenticate using (java+oauth)? Why people for front end authentication compared to backend(java)? Does it give any performance boost without loosing on security?